# Use variable in jq read query

Tags: json, bash, variables, iteration, jq

I have the following json file

```
cat permissions.json

{
  "foo1.bar1@email.com": [
    "projects/development/roles/superadmin",
    "compute.networkAdmin"
  ],
  "foo2.bar2@email.co": [
    "compute.networkAdmin"
  ]
}
```

Now I can do something like this quite well with `jq`

```
$ jq -r '.["foo1.bar1@email.com"]' permissions.json
[
  "projects/development/roles/superadmin",
   "compute.networkAdmin"
]
```

Now the email needs to come from a variable

So my for loop is such that

```
for USER in $(jq -r 'keys[]' permissions.json)
do
  echo ${USER}
  for ROLE in $(jq -r '.["$USER"][]' permissions.json)
  do
    echo "User ${USER} has role ${ROLE}"
  done
done
```

But when I run

```
./compare-permissions.sh
foo1.bar1@email.com
jq: error (at permissions.json:9): Cannot iterate over null (null)
foo2.bar2@email.co
jq: error (at permissions.json:9): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Ive tried sending the var as an `--arg`. Ive done something like this

```
USER=foo1.bar1@email.com
jq -r --arg USER "$USER" '.["$USER"][] | select(.[]==$USER)'  permissions.json
```

But the result is empty. So how can I use the email as a variable and extract the permissions out of it using `jq` ?

Comment: Note that `for var in $(anything)` is bad practice -- if there's a `*` surrounded by whitespace in jq's output, you'll find yourself iterating over filenames (as just one of the many possible bugs). See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for explanation, and [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of the best-practice way to iterate over an input stream line-by-line.

Comment: If you really want to keep the current structure, preceding your code with `IFS=$'\n'` doesn't fix the unwanted globbing (`set -f` will do that, but it disables *all* globbing, so you'll often want to reverse it with `set +f` later), but changing IFS alone *does* at least stop the output from jq from being split on other whitespace in addition to newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use string interpolation; pass the variable as an argument.

```
for user in $(jq -r 'keys[]' permissions.json)
do
  echo ${user}
  for role in $(jq --arg u "$user" -r '.[$u][]' permissions.json)
  do
    echo "User ${user} has role ${role}"
  done
done
```

Also, don't use for loops to iterate over the output of a command. Use a `while` loop and the `read` command.

```
while IFS= read -r user; do
  echo "$user"
  while IFS= read -r role; do
    echo "User $user has role $role"
  done < <(jq --arg u "$user" -r '.[$u][]' permissions.json
done < <(jq -r 'keys[]' permissions.json)
```

However, you may not need a shell loop at all.

```
% jq -r 'keys[] as $user | .[$user][] | "User \($user) has role \(.)"' permissions.json
User foo1.bar1@email.com has role projects/development/roles/superadmin
User foo1.bar1@email.com has role compute.networkAdmin
User foo2.bar2@email.co has role compute.networkAdmin
```

Comment: Thumbs-up for the no-shell-loop answer, *grumble* for keeping the `for var in $(...)` idiom.

Comment: Ugh, fiiiine. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$USER` won't be expanded since it's in single quotes. You can use arg:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                        

for USER in $(jq -r 'keys[]' permissions.json)                                                                                                                                                                     
do                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  echo ${USER}                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  for ROLE in $(jq --arg u "$USER" -r '.[$u][]' permissions.json)                                                                                                                                                  
  do                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    echo "User ${USER} has role ${ROLE}"                                                                                                                                                                           
  done                                                                                                                                                                                                             
done
```

or to extract a permissions for one user:

```
USER=foo1.bar1@email.com                                                                                                                                                                                           
jq --arg USER "$USER" -r '.[$USER][]' permissions.json
```